# Javascript not working on new bootstrap site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have to recode a website with bootstrap. The previous site version has a working script while on the new version the script does not work.
http://sacim-design.esy.es/ new site

http://test.denkmann.ro old version with working script.

Here is the fiddle with the javascript. [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/developerwannabe/73wan053/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var studii='Solutii standard sau dezvoltate in stansa colaborare cu clientul , in functie de specificul fiecarui caz. Transportul mostrelor de tesut, analizelor de sange  sau componentelor sensibile ale aparaturii medicale reprezinta o provocare la care raspundem cu solutii fiabile si de incredere pentru clienti din diferite sectoare de activitate: laboratoare medicale, lanturi de farmacii, producatori de medicamente, banci de celule si de sange.';
    var standard='<div class="appButtonSelected">VEZI PRODUSELE</div>';
    var vet='Problemele trasportului la temperatura controlata din domeniul veterinar sunt comune  pana la un anumit punct cu cele din medicina umana. Insa uneori este nevoie de solutii special dezvoltate pentru activitati specifice domeniului veterinar, cum ar fi transportul animalelor cu sange rece-reptile si amfibieni sau activitati adiacente: incubarea/inmultirea serpilor, soparlelor, testoaselor pentru practica veterinara. '
    var alimentar='Cunoastem foarte bine probemele cu care se confunta companiile din domeniul transportului alimentar. Experienta noastra si posibilitatea de a efectua teste in propriul laborator de incercari ne recomanda  ca un partener de incredere pentru producatorii si transportatorii de alimente speciale, perisabile sau inghetate. Avand in vedere variabilele multiple din acest sector, am dezvoltat de-a lungul timpului solutii ingenioase de design si functionalitate.'
    var logistic='De la mic la mare, in logistica fiabilitatea si exigenta germane fac diferenta.La orice intrebare oferim cel mai bun raspuns, fie ca este vorba de transporturi voluminoase pentru perioade mai indelungate de timp sau de perioade de transit mai reduse. De asemenea, prin parteneriatul cu LogTag® putem pune la dispozitie recordere de transport, care reflecta indicatorii de temperatura pe toate durata expeditiei produselor. '
    var farma='Produsele termo-sensibile din industriile farmaceutica si biotehnologie trebuie sa fie de obicei transportate si depozitate in medii cu o temperatura cuprinsa intre 2-8 °C controlata, ferite de fluctuatii termice si radiatia solara. Pe durata transportului si stocarii medicamentelor alimentelor si altor produse termo-sensibile, cutiile izolatoare din EPS asigura o protectie excelenta fata de caldura si umeazeala.'
    $(".appButton").click(function(){
       $(".appButtonSelected").attr('class','appButton');
       $(this).addClass('appButtonSelected');
       if($(this).attr('id')==='studii')
       {
           $(".appInfoText").css('display','none');
           $(".appInfotext").html(studii);
           $(".appInfotext").append(standard);
           $("#faramcist").attr('src','public/images/background_'+$(this).attr('id')+'.png')
            $(".appInfoText").fadeIn(2000);
       }
       if($(this).attr('id')==='alimentar')
       {$(".appInfoText").css('display','none');
           $(".appInfotext").html(alimentar);
            $(".appInfotext").append(standard);
            $("#faramcist").attr('src','public/images/background_'+$(this).attr('id')+'.png')
            $(".appInfoText").fadeIn(2000);
       }
       if($(this).attr('id')==='farma')
       {$(".appInfoText").css('display','none');
           $(".appInfotext").html(farma);
            $(".appInfotext").append(standard);
            $("#faramcist").attr('src','public/images/background_'+$(this).attr('id')+'.png')
            $(".appInfoText").fadeIn(2000);
       }
       if($(this).attr('id')==='vet')
       {$(".appInfoText").css('display','none');
           $(".appInfotext").html(vet);
            $(".appInfotext").append(standard);
            $("#faramcist").attr('src','public/images/background_'+$(this).attr('id')+'.png')
            $(".appInfoText").fadeIn(2000);
       }
       if($(this).attr('id')==='logistic')
       {$(".appInfoText").css('display','none');
           $(".appInfotext").html(logistic);
            $(".appInfotext").append(standard);
            $("#faramcist").attr('src','public/images/background_'+$(this).attr('id')+'.png')
            $(".appInfoText").fadeIn(2000);
            console.log($("#faramcist"));
       }
   });
$("#studii").trigger('click');

});
```

Comment: I wonder why do you people post links to your sites. Ads?

Comment: It is not my website, I can post the whole HTML and the CSS but there are hundreds of lines of code.

Comment: Just extract interesting lines, that's all. Also, please describe exact problem, not just `the script does not work`.

Comment: Please read the [ask] page. Create a [mcve]. I bet that not all of the hundreds of lines of code are affecting your problem, but just a small subset that you should isolate to post here.

Comment: Do you get any JavaScript errors or warnings?

Comment: What part of the script is not working? I see it add/removing the `.appButtonSelected` class. Are you trying to get description text to show up via `.appInfoText`? If so, there is no element on the page with `.appInfoText` as far as I can see. Try adding that element to the page.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things that you have not migrated to the new version correctly. The quick and short of it is, ***your new markup and CSS classes to not match that of the old.***

***1)*** There is no `.appInfoText` element on the new version. Though there is a DIV with `.prodtext` where the old `.appInfoText` DIV was. The script, if it were identifying elements property (see #2), wouldn't have anywhere to place the text as `.appInfoText` doesn't exist.

***2)*** The old version has:

```html
<div class="appButton" id="[some id]">
    <span>[text here]</span>
</div`>
```

where the new version has:

```html
<div class="appButton">
    <p style="text-align: center;" id="[some id]">[text here]</p>
</div>
```

Notice that the `id`, which the script uses, has been moved to a different element, breaking the text swapping of the script (along with #1).

Abbreviated version of script showing a single `if` statement:

```js
$( ".appButton" ).click( function() {

    if ( $( this ).attr( 'id' ) === 'studii' ) {
      $( ".appInfoText" ).css( 'display', 'none' );
      $( ".appInfotext" ).html( studii );
      $( ".appInfotext" ).append( standard );
      $( "#faramcist" ).attr( 'src', 'public/images/background_' + $( this ).attr( 'id' ) + '.png' );
      $( ".appInfoText" ).fadeIn( 2000 );
    }

}
```

`$( this )` refers to the element that was clicked having the class `.appButton`. The script checks to see if the `.appButton` element as and ID equal to *studii*, it does not since the ID is now on a different element, the child `<p>`.

### How to Fix?

**Easy answer:** Make sure your markup is the same and have have IDs and classes on the correct elements, that is, the relevant parts like outlined above. I don't see a reason the ID needs to be on the `<p>`.

**Still easy, a little work answer:** Fix the script.

Where you have `.appInfoText` change it to `.prodtext`. Instead of `$( this ).attr( 'id' )` which looks at the DIV with .`appButton`, make it look at the `<p>` with the ID you need to check, `$( this ).children( 'p' ).attr( 'id' )`.

---

That might not be every single thing that needs to be adjusted but will get you a long ways and pointed in the right direction on how to debug the issues you're seeing.

On a side note, if you're going to adjust the script I would like to make some suggestions.

***1)*** Cache references to elements so you don't query them every time you need access to them. Instead of:

```
if ( $( this ).attr( 'id' ) === 'studii' ) {}
if ( $( this ).attr( 'id' ) === 'alimentar' ) {}
if ( $( this ).attr( 'id' ) === 'farma' ) {}
```

Do:

```
var $this = $( this );
var $id = $this.attr( 'id' );

$this.addClass( 'appButtonSelected' );
if ( $id === 'studii' ) {}
if ( $id === 'alimentar' ) {}
if ( $id === 'farma' ) {}
```

***2)*** jQuery allows you to chain method calls. Instead of:

```
$( ".appInfoText ").css( 'display', 'none' );
$( ".appInfoText ").html( studii );
$( ".appInfoText ").append( standard );
```

Do:

```
$( '.appInfoText' ).css( 'display', 'none' ).html( studii ).append( standard );
```

I would used the [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method over [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) if you're not inserting any markup.

I'm not sure I'd store the content strings in JS like the script does, but that's more than I feel like getting into.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!